# Sql trouble with coalesce() not working propely

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i have a query and i'm having trouble to change the name of the last row of columb name to 'TOTAL'. The result gives me the same name of the row above the last row.
Here's my query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ticket_types.name,'TOTAL') AS name, 
COUNT(1) AS quantity 
FROM tr_logs 
LEFT JOIN tickets ON tr_logs.value = tickets.id 
LEFT JOIN ticket_types ON tickets.ticket_type_id = ticket_types.id 
LEFT JOIN transactions ON tr_logs.transaction_id = transactions.id 
LEFT JOIN tr_fields_data AS tfd_shipping ON tfd_shipping.transaction_id = transactions.id 
WHERE type = 'ADDITEM' 
AND transactions.event_id = '46' 
AND DATE(tr_logs.created_date) 
BETWEEN '2017-03-26' AND '2017-05-24' 
AND tfd_shipping.data IN ('0','570','571','771') 
AND name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ticket_types.id WITH ROLLUP
```

The result looks like this:

```
name      quantity
premium   56
outlaw    6
outlaw    62
```

Last row name from rollup is not null.... I need it to be TOTAL and not outlaw

Thanks

Comment: I just don't see what is happening:  "the same name of the row above the last row".

Comment: The result is something like this:                                                      
name quantity
premium  56
outlaw  6
outlaw 14217

Comment: Last row name from rollup is not null, It has same name has previous row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gordon Linoff I have figure out my problem.

The name of the last row was never null beacause i GROUP BY with a different attribute.

Here's the solution.

```
SELECT COALESCE(tckn,'TOTAL') AS name, quantity FROM
(SELECT tt.name AS tckn, COUNT(1) AS quantity 
FROM tr_logs AS l
LEFT JOIN tickets AS t ON l.value = t.id 
LEFT JOIN ticket_types AS tt ON t.ticket_type_id = tt.id 
LEFT JOIN transactions AS tr ON l.transaction_id = tr.id 
LEFT JOIN tr_fields_data AS tfd ON tfd.transaction_id = tr.id 
WHERE type = 'ADDITEM' 
AND tr.event_id = '46' 
AND DATE(l.created_date) 
BETWEEN '2017-03-26' AND '2017-05-24' 
AND tfd.data IN ('0','570','571','771')
GROUP BY tckn WITH ROLLUP) as sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't changed the name to `TOTAL` at all: you've changed the name of the column to `name`, and you've told it to replace any null values with `TOTAL`.

If you want to change the name of `ticket_types.name` to `total`, you just want

```
SELECT ticket_types.name AS total ...
```

(But it would be weird to rename something called `name` to `total`, so perhaps you need to clarify your requirements a little.)

Comment: My last row is a rollup. I sum the columb quantity. But on that row i want to have TOTAL next to the sum. Right now the last row has the same name of the previous row  with the sum.  I want TOTAL and the sum

Answer (score 0):

This may or not be related to your observed problem, but the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clauses turn all the outer joins into inner joins.  You should simplify the query to:

```
SELECT COALESCE(tt.name, 'TOTAL') AS name, COUNT(1) AS quantity 
FROM tr_logs l JOIN
     tickets
     ON l.value = t.id JOIN
     ticket_types tt
     ON t.ticket_type_id = tt.id JOIN
     transactions tr
     ON l.transaction_id = tr.id JOIN
     tr_fields_data fd
     ON fd.transaction_id = tr.id 
WHERE type = 'ADDITEM' AND
      tr.event_id = '46' AND
      DATE(l.created_date) BETWEEN '2017-03-26' AND '2017-05-24' AND 
      fd.data IN ('0', '570', '571', '771') AND
      tt.name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY tt.id WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i tested your query and the rusult is the same. Also my boss dont like alias, so i dont do it has much.